# Why does this function prints what has been scanned when it finishes the first loop? Specially When i enter more than 1 character?

Tags: c, codeblocks

Using Code::Blocks, I wrote code that checks if the user entered a lowercase or an uppercase, by scanning the input from the user, which is a character, and passing it to a function to return either 1 or 0.

So, what I don't understand is, why "please enter a letter 0" is printed.

My best guess is because `scanf` stacked the null character, and it is saved, so it had to check if this letter is uppercase or not as well.

If I'm right, how do I avoid this problem?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char CapsCheck (char c)
{
    if (c >= 65 && c<= 90 )
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("please enter a letter: ");
        scanf("%c",&c);
        printf("%d\n",CapsCheck(c));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
please enter a letter: C
1
please enter a letter: 0
please enter a letter:
```

Comment: `scanf("%c"` reads also the newline character (`'\n'`). Try `scanf(" %c", &c)`, which will skip leading whitespace characters.

Comment: You can change the `"%c"` to `" %c"` to make `scanf` skip initial whitespace before reading a non-whitespace character.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  I fixed it for you THIS TIME (lol).  I would get rid of `scanf`.  It's temperamental as hell if you don't know all its pitfalls.  If you just need a character, maybe try `getchar`?

Comment: Side note: Instead of writing your own function `CapsCheck`, you can simply use the function [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) from the header file `ctype.h`. Using that function also has the advantage that it also works for other [locales](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is related to one **big** misconception that students (and teachers) have: you expect the C language to know about "the keyboard".

There's no keyboard in the standard, nor any "screen" or "monitor". You only have files. So each operating system has it's version of a special file, which is the console, that works as an interface with your keyboard and screen.

Specifically, when you try to read from `stdio` (the call to `scanf`) the console asks you for a line of text. You entered

```
C↲
```

which is the sequence of two bytes: `67` and `10`.

The first `scanf` reads `67`, then it prints `1↲`. Then you print `please enter a letter:` , a second `scanf` reads `10`, then it prints `0↲`. Then you print `please enter a letter:` .

You need to take care of what is left on `stdio` by the console processing.

**And** you should definitely check if your `scanf` managed to read a character, by comparing its return value to 1.

## Edit

The [return value of `scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#:%7E:text=behavior%20is%20undefined.-,Return%20value,-1%2D3) is "Number of receiving arguments successfully assigned (which may be zero in case a matching failure occurred before the first receiving argument was assigned), or EOF if input failure occurs before the first receiving argument was assigned."

This is how you could do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char CapsCheck (char c)
{
    if (c >= 65 && c <= 90 ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("please enter a letter: ");
        int res = scanf("%c",&c);     // (Try to) Read
        if (res != 1) {               // Check
            break;                    // Exit if reading failed
        }
        printf("%d\n", CapsCheck(c)); // Use what was read
        
        // Skip everything that is in the current line
        while (1) {
            int x = fgetc(stdin);
            if (x == EOF || x == '\n') {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you explain the last part where you say comparing the return value of scanf to 1? Why is that useful and how it is done?

Secondly,

How to take care of what is left on stdio? by using fflush(stdin)?

Comment: @AhmedEl-Shaer Check the edited answer. Notice that `fflush(stdin)` is not defined in the standard. So, it *may* work in your system.